# Intellij doesn't allow .db file to be version controlled?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have a local database file named 'fold.db', but it doesn't appear in the changelist, and it seems there is no way for me to add it to a changelist for commit. However, if I run "git statu" on a terminal, 'fold.db' is shown as one untracked file.

Why is that and how to make it version controlled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check two things:

1. You might be able to git add that file rom the command line
2. The IDE itself might be configured to ignore that file: see [IntelliJ "Defining a list of ignored files"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-ignored-files.html)

[image: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2017.2/configureIgnoredFiles.png]

That is not tied to Git itself.

> You can create a global ignore list that will be stored in the workspace file and applied to all supported version control systems.

In your case, check if IntelliJ is configured  to ignore `*.db` files.